# Using File System Object to read a line

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I have a textbox where people insert an abbreviated word to search for it's whole meaning.

The search is being done in a database that is a txt file. I am using the File System Object to do so.

When a word is searched and found in the text file, I need to return the string from the **next line**, that is, the meaning. Take a look at the txt format below:

MS

Microsoft

SO

StackOverflow

How can I do that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have some code, we can look at?

Comment: show your current code and see [**this**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You match against the current line so

`if (oFS.ReadLine = search_text) then` checks for a match

and then if that's true then

`Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = oFS.ReadLine`

jumps to the next line and saved it in your column A

```
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath)
Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream
    if (oFS.ReadLine = search_text) then
        Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = oFS.ReadLine
    end if
Loop
oFS.Close
```